# Why do people say 'topless' but not 'topful'?

Tags: word-usage, suffixes

Say you want to wear a shirt: it would be odd to say, "I'm going [topful](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Topful)". Is the reason due to topless being more out of the norm, and thus requiring a term? Maybe in places where not wearing a shirt is more normal, topful may be a more likely word to exist. Or maybe topful sounds like it would be totally covered, so the term isn't used. Or maybe the suffix 'less' often isn't paired with a converse version with 'ful'. Or maybe it's a combination of these things. In any case, any ideas why topful is not said?

*Topful* is indeed a word, but that doesn't seem to apply here:

> *Full to the top, or brim; brimfull.* (Webster)

Comment: See also: ["harmless vs harmful"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611527/why-do-people-say-a-dog-is-harmless-but-not-harmful)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148209/discussion-on-question-by-user486316-why-do-people-say-topless-but-not-topful); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 35):

Kenneth Holmqvist and Jarosław Płuciennik discuss this in *[Conceptualised Deviations from Expected Normalties: A Semantic Comparison Between Lexical Terms Ending in -ful and -less](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=804c0ecbcac2512d2c596fcc2037a7f77e3a2919)*. This is more of a formal examination than a practical one, so I should say now that your interpretation of the reason seems to be correct.

> **10.1. Adjectives meaning that a specified part is lacking.**
>
> [Here,] we find examples such as *bloodless*, *brainless*, *earless*, *fingerless*, *finless*, *footless*, *roofless*, *rootless*, *toothless*, *verandaless*, *waterless*. Here *-less* evokes a whole (such as body for *bloodless*) which is normally expected to have the lacking concrete part mentioned in the stem. It is relatively easy to predict what whole *toothless* and *brainless* refer to, even without any context. Not only do they evoke wholes which are denoted by nouns, the things that can be *bloodless* is a much more restricted group than the things that can be green, soft, or even beautiful.
>
> In other words, when a speaker uses a word like *bloodless*, *fingerless* or *roofless*, s/he creates a very restricted context from the expected whole with the stem part missing. Although a restricted context, the whole may be a semantically rich concept, such as the war in *bloodless* *war*. The listener receiving *bloodless* automatically experiences the expectation of several such possible rich wholes (except for war, also body, film, victory, coup, statistics).
>
> [...]
>
> **The reason that there are no *-ful* adjectives corresponding to this group of *-less* adjectives should be obvious: There are not many things normally without fingers that we would want to say are *fingerful*, so *fingerful* can almost only express either what is already expected and nothing special (fingerful hand; a hand with fingers) or what is a weird anomaly (fingerful house). Using *fingerful* is therefore pointless. Had *-ful* expressed a process leading to the state (as does *-filled*), the anomalies could have been resolved: Compare *bloodful* barrel to *blood-filled* barrel. But *-ful* only refers to the state itself.**
>
> Also, as we will see, -ful requires there to be a container involved, and normally these adjectival stems are not placed in containers. It is difficult to conceptualise the hand as a container that is possible to fill with fingers.

Though *topless* is not discussed here specifically, it is the same phenomenon at play.

> Here *-less* evokes a whole (such as body for *bloodless*) which is normally expected to have the lacking concrete part mentioned in the stem.

(*Topless* evokes a person [whole] lacking a top [stem])

The paper has an appendixful of such words; other members of this category include *lidless*, *spotless*, *treeless*, etc.

Comment: You just blew everyone away.  Incredible answer that makes the site worthwhile!

Answer (score 21):

Why, I'm not quite sure, but women can be topless but not men, unless it's said facetiously.

When a man doesn't wear a shirt, he's "bare chested" or "shirtless". Likewise when a man wears a shirt he is *dressed* or *clothed*, he is not "shirtful".

Not every noun with the suffix ***-less*** has its equivalent ***-full***; e.g. *childless* , *childful* (?);  *headless*,  *headful (?)*; *homeless, homeful (?)*

Comment: in a similar vein, an article of clothing worn on the upper body by a man is rarely if ever called "a top" but one worn by a woman sometimes is called "a top"

Comment: Don't think too hard about English. It's not designed for that.

Comment: But "shirtless" and "topless" would mean different things when applied to women, wouldn't they? Someone wearing a sports bra is shirtless but not topless.

Comment: Maybe because men don't wear "tops," but women do?

Comment: @Robusto  Could be but I'm not entirely certain that tops were a thing in the late 50s and 60s, I think it means **the top half of the body** is naked.

Comment: OK, but I don't think "topless" could mean you are without the top half of your body. ^_^

Comment: re tops, men in the West usually wear shirts (formal, button-up, dress, etc), t-shirts, or jumpers/sweaters/pullovers; women commonly wear a far larger range of tops (camisoles, crop tops, bandeaus, blouses of various types, bustiers, corsets, short-sleeved sweaters, tank tops, bralets, etc). Nonetheless, you can find "top" used in clothes store websites for men as well as women. (Jackets and coats are normally in a separate category.)

Comment: I fundamentally disagree that you wouldn't say that a man is "topless". @eques - I also wouldn't agree that you wouldn't say a man in a t-shirt or polo has a top on. This could, however, be a US/UK thing though.

Comment: Do you have a source that topless only applies to women? That's certainly not the case in my experience. I'd happily describe both men and women to be topless. Likewise "shirtless" applies to both IME.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater It certainly could be dialectal; I was mostly pointing out that the use of "topless" seemed to correlate with whether "top" was a generic term for an upper body garment

Comment: @eques - Might be worth an edit to clarify that? I'd personally argue that any garment worn directly on the skin on the upper part of the body is a top be that a shirt, blouse, polo, tee, etc.

Comment: @Tim I didn't say that the term *only* applies to women, it can be used facetiously for men, too. If a celebrity goes topless on a beach, it's very often associated with a woman not a man. A man who bares his chest walking along a busy street is not "scandalous"  but it's considered indecent when a woman does.  If someone says she went shirtless, I'd think she had a vest (UK) or a camisole on, and her breasts were covered.

Comment: Mari-Lou may remember this, having written the question a few years ago, but [*The first "topless" man*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391311/48571) has some relevant discussion  (@Tim et al.)

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I'm not the OP; I was merely adding to the conversation. I'll leave it to others to decide whether my comment is significant enough to add to the answer

Comment: [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=topless+man%2Ctopless+men%2Ctopless+woman%2Ctopless+women&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). I disagree that male use is only facetious. It's only less commonly used because it's less commonly noteworthy.

Comment: *"If a celebrity goes topless on a beach, it's very often associated with a woman not a man."* << This has nothing to do with facetiousness or the meaning of "topless", it's just that tabloids only report information that they judge interesting. "A man was topless on a beach" is grammatically correct, but is typically not considered worthy of a headline.

Comment: Topless has little to do with shirts.  A woman can be shirtless and not topless.  It's a specific term used for exposed breasts.  Topless beach, topless bar/club, etc...source is Oxford Dictionary

Comment: The main reason that 'shirtless' and 'topless' normally mean the same thing for men and not for women (at least in the U.S.) is that shirts are the only type of tops that men normally wear here (aside from coats and such, which are normally worn on top of a shirt,) while women very frequently wear clothing that covers part or all of their torso that is not a shirt. As a result, if a man is 'shirtless,' it is normally understood that his chest/torso is not covered, while the same is not true for a woman who might still be fully dressed, just with something other than a shirt (e.g. a dress.)

Answer (score 11):

Adjectives formed on the pattern X-less when applied to a noun indicate that the noun lacks X.

Someone who is graceless lacks grace.

Adjectives formed on the pattern X-ful when applied to a noun indicate that the noun is full of X.

> They were hopeful that the rain would stop.

They were full of hope that the rain would stop.

**Full** has a variety of related meanings. It isn't always as simple as a pitcher being filled with water. When someone is **helpful**, help  comes from them; they have help to give and give it.

If you don't have a shirt on, you are *topless*, lacking a top, without a top, a "top" being something you wear on your torso, sometimes also on your shoulders, and sometimes also on your arms.

If you do have a shirt on, your are not "full of top".  You are "wearing a shirt".  The situation  simply doesn't call for a -ful adjective.

FWIW, X-ful and X-less adjectives do not not always have semantically opposite meanings.

Comment: You're the only one answering the core of the question rather than speculating about cultural norms. Well done.

Answer (score 9):

Such words are called **"[unpaired words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpaired_word)"** or **"orphan words"**.

These are words which seem like they should have an obvious "opposite word" or "antonym", but when you create that obvious antonym, it is not a widely recognized term in English.

- distressful -> stressful is not an antonym.
- inflammable -> flammable is not an antonym.
- ruthless -> ruthful is archaic.
- feckless -> feckful is regional Scottish.
- reckless -> reckful not typically considered a word.
- gormless -> gormful not typically considered a word.
- superstitious -> stitious not typically considered a word.
- nonchalant -> chalant not typically considered a word.
- disheveled -> heveled not typically considered a word.
- disgruntled -> gruntled rarely used.
- innocent -> nocent is archaic.

Even where there is an antonym, there are a few different ways to create an antonym of a "-less" word. There's at least "-ful", "-y", "-ed", "-ous", "-able", likely more.

Comment: Good answer, but "superstitious" seems odd on this list - wouldn't the obvious opposite be "substitious" for "standing under"? Not that I'm not tickled by the idea of things being slightly stitious or moderately stitious...

Comment: Although "dishevelled" looks like it has a _dis-_ prefix, it's unrelated.  It derives from Old French _descheveler_.  And, in a parallel with "inflammable"/"flammable", "shevelled" has the same meaning as "dishevelled".

Comment: surprised to see that unkempt did not put in an appearance there!

Comment: @Deipatrous "Kempt" [is a valid word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kempt), and the opposite of "unkempt," thus it does not belong on this list.

Comment: I've seen "stressful" often but never "distressful".

Comment: @ikegami - Maybe, but that doesn't seem to fit the linked Wikipedia page (where it doesn't appear). I think "superstitious" is closer to the idea of a morphological gap, with "super-" being a Latin preposition rather than a prefix. But English is weird. I'm happy to sit on that one and risk an accusation of supersedition.

Answer (score 7):

> Is the reason due to topless being more out of the norm, and thus requiring a term?

Yes. I suppose that, in linguistic terms, "topless" is culturally abnormal in the country of origin of English, chiefly on account of British weather and a Christian moral ethic. In Kenyan tribal terms, for example, I assume that the equivalent strange but essential adjective will equate to "dressed above the waist."

If you take the example of "a carriage arrived at the farm" in Old English, one assumes that, as most carriages were drawn by oxen, an adjective would only be necessary if it were drawn by horses or some other animal.

However, by the 16th century, ox-drawn carriages were becoming rare and it would be "horse-drawn" that would be assumed.

By the late 19th/early 20th century the "horseless" carriage appeared and, as these were rare, an adjective had to be used.

Not unreasonably, all words carry a nuance and this is often cultural.

We don't need a word for "topful" as "topful" is the cultural default.

Comment: "-ful" is only rarely the opposite of "-less".Take your own example: nobody ever spoke of a "horseful" carriage. And even if they did, it would mean a carriage full of horses, not a carriage drawn by horses.

Comment: @TonyK The question was "In any case, any ideas why topful is not said?" The actual form of the adjective seems irrelevant.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, the actual form would presumably be "topped" (by analogy with "hatless" vs "hatted"), but for the reasons you give isn't actually used.

Answer (score 7):

Your last supposition is nearest, I think: "Maybe the suffix *-less* often isn't paired with a converse of *-ful.*"

Where the *-less* or *-ful* means "without" or "having", it's by no means a given that they are capable of being exchanged to change the meaning.

It does (more-or-less) work with *mindful/mindless, careful/careless,* or even *wonderful/wonderless,* but *roofless* can't be given a roof to become **roofful; topless* can't be given a shirt to become **topful.*

Where *-ful* actually means *full*, you can't say "less than full" as in **spoonless.*

Comment: Resourceful and resourceless, masterful and masterless show different semantic relations. Merciful and merciless are antonyms, but grateful and grateless aren't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly, as I hinted in my answer. *Spoonful* is a quantity; but *spoonless* doesn't even have a spoon.

Comment: Roofful isn't a word, but "roofed" and "treed" are.  "Shirted" also is, but "topped" means something else.  ("Shirted" is rarely used alone and it sounds weird, perhaps fully incorrect, to say "I saw a shirted man".  But seems fine to say "I saw some red-shirted men".)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's completely different and has nothing to do with *-ful.*

Comment: I thought it was interesting that there *is* a word with the meaning the OP was looking for, it's just not "topful", and nobody has mentioned "shirted".  Also that some of the other examples you picked do have an "-ed" form as a near antonym to the "-ful" form, unlike "topped"... but fair enough, explaining why for all those things is quite a bit broader.